# Strange behaviour of viewScope with timeZone attribute

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Markup:

```
    <h:head>
        <title>title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{viewScopeBacking.date}">
            <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{viewScopeBacking.timeZone}"/>
        </h:outputText>

        <h:commandButton action="#{viewScopeBacking.action}" value="submit">
            <f:ajax event="action" render="op"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:outputText value="#{viewScope.view}" id="op"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class viewScopeBacking {

    public viewScopeBacking() {
    }
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{viewScope}")
    Map<String, Object> viewMap;
    private Date date = new Date();
    private TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

    public void action() {
        getViewMap().put("view", "hello world");
    }

    //getters and setters
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public TimeZone getTimeZone() {
        return timeZone;
    }

    public void setTimeZone(TimeZone timeZone) {
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getViewMap() {
        return viewMap;
    }

    public void setViewMap(Map<String, Object> viewMap) {
        this.viewMap = viewMap;
    }
}
```

Upon pressing the button, the outputText should be updated by theory. But this is not happening until you remove the timeZone attribute of convertDateTime.

Comment: How is this [java] **and** [c] **and** [.net] ?

Comment: But you added C and NET to the tags. They doesn't make any sense in this question, so Marc removed them (and I replaced JSP tag by JSF tag since you aren't using JSP at all, but Facelets)

Answer (score 0):

use `<f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{Application.timeZone}"/>`

instead of your ManagedBean.

at least this solved my problem. let me know if you know the reason.

cheers